# How to change thickness of a single in line in EXISTING plot

Tags: plot, cygwin, gnuplot

I create a plot with many (50+) lines on it.

I would like to set up a keybind such that I can toggle through each line and change it's thickness, and so making that line stand-out from the rest, then when I press the key again, the next line becomes thicker.

That way I can examine each line clearly, next to the others.

I know how to assign keys, but I don't know how to change the thickness of an exiting line on an existing plot.

How can I go about this?

Moon

EDIT 1

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "red" lw 3
set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "orange" lw 2
set style line 3 lt 2 lc rgb "yellow" lw 3
set style line 4 lt 2 lc rgb "green" lw 

savedls1 = ls 1
savedls2 = ls 2
savedls3 = ls 3
savedls4 = ls 4

plot <whatever> ls 2    #Original style

set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "black" lw 2 #new temp style

plot <whatever> ls 2; replot  #Temp new style

set style line 2 savedls2

plot <whatever> ls 2; replot  #Back to original style
```

Answer (score 1):

In the command line (v4.6 patchlevel 3), you can do it like this:

1. [Specify a line style](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node237.html):

   ```
   set style line 1 lt 2 lw 2 pt 3 ps 0.5
   ```
2. When plotting, specify this line style:

   ```
   plot sin(x) ls 1
   ```
3. Now, you can change this line style, e.g. changing the line width:

   ```
   set style line 1 lt 2 lw 4 pt 3 ps 0.5
   ```
4. A simple `replot` will produce the same graph with the updated line style.

**EDIT**
Christoph provided this information in a comment, addressing the question of a key-bind:
It is enough in step 3 to change the linewidth, the rest remains unchanged:

```
set style line 1 lw 4
```

That would allow you to define two different linewidths and toggle between them:

```
lw_small = 2
lw_thick = 5

set style line 1 lt 2 lw lw_small pt 3 ps 0.5

plot sin(x) ls 1

set style line 1 lw lw_thick # here, everything but the line-width stays constant

pause 3
replot

set style line 1 lw lw_small

pause 3
replot
```

Comment: OK. That's a good start. Is there a way in a keybind I could say. Temporarily change ls1 to "thick line etc" and then revert to original ls later?